# OpenTok has duplicated sessions in MS Teams integration on IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, microsoft-teams, opentok, tokbox

guys. I use IPhone 7 (IOS version is 15.0). I am integrating app in MS Teams application. My app uses OpenTok. I faced with the next problem: when user open tab of my app in meeting, new session created. It's correct. After that user returns to the main screen of the meeting (session of my app is on - it's correct too) and opens tab of my app again. When tab opens old session is continuing to work and new session created too. And that is wrong, because i expect that old session will be destroy (like on desktop version). I have one code for desktop and mobile. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

From our [sessions docs](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/create-session/), OpenTok sessions do not expire. However, authentication tokens do expire. Also, note that sessions cannot explicitly be destroyed. You can create very short-lived tokens, so when a user leaves a tab they will not be able to reenter. More information is available here: https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/create-token/

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft - Unfortunately not. As I mentioned above, I use the same code for the mobile and desktop versions, and in the desktop version, when leaving the tab, the session ends.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft, do you have another ideas?

Comment: @AlexMac can you reach out to our support. My understanding is that even in the web browser your sessions should not destroy. I guess the iOS app is keeping the view controller or something in memory.